# Find domain object with multiple ID attributes?

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I fetch a domain object that has multiple `@Id` attributes defined?

```
class Test {
    @Id
    private String first;

    @Id
    private String second;
}

//how can I pass multiple IDs to find with entitymanger?
em.find(Test.class, id);
```

Comment: no you can not, `@id` annotate a field to be the primary key of an table. there can not have duplicated primary key in one table. but you could try to setup a primary which includes two fields! but I think in JPA, they design this to have one field. U can try it if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use either `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId` annotations to map composite primary key (see [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id#Composite_Primary_Key_) for details). 
Then you pass instance of composite class to `find` method.

So basically your example would be something like that:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(TestPK.class)
public class Test {

@Id
private String first;
@Id
private String second;

}

TestPk {

private String first;
private String second;

}

em.find(Test.class, testPKInstance);
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of `IdClass` over `EmbeddedId` or vice versa?